# Apache runs the image files as PHP files

Tags: image, apache, php-7

I updated PHP to PHP7, but the apache configuration went wrong. It doesn't read files directly and PHP deal with them. I did a test, I wrote `<?php echo "hello world"?>` into a txt file and renamed it as test.jpg. And it shows 'hello world' when you visit the jpg file. I can't find where the error is.

This is the test url: http://shouke.luopan.me/test.jpg

Comment: You'll need to show the configuration to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change header content type :

```
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
```